# Npm cannot find module 'cropit'

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I cannot get npm to recognize that I have installed cropit. My package.json contains relevant lines like these:

```
"cropit": "^0.1.9",
"jquery": "~2.1.1"
```

Did I pick an incorrect version? Am I using versions of jquery and cropit that don't work together?

I am importing the modules with these lines, which is working perfectly for my import of Bootstrap.

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
require('cropit');
```

Comment: have you run `npm install cropit` ?

Comment: or just `npm install` if it's already in your package.json

Comment: I have tried both of those, the module is definitely installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that cropit is not actually CommonJs compatible. Therefore, when you try and require it on the frontend or backend, it won't work, because it doesn't specify what to export. You should try using something like browserify-shim to make this CommonJs compatible.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Mike and Ilan, the package.json is metadata for your package. To use the metadata to install dependencies, run `npm install` in the folder where your `package.json` is located.

You have 'cropit' flagged "compatible with version" (see here: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html). You may want to choose a more or less specific version. The current version is 0.1.9. (see here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/cropit)

If it is still not working, delete your global **and** local node_modules cache and try installing again. Please refer to the following link for the location of your global nod_modules cache. https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have tried that. The module is definitely installed, but it still cannot be found. I'm thinking it might have to do with the versions I am using.